# What is "sleep" supposed to do in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

In my start menu, one of the power options is called "sleep". When I select it, it brings up the windows splash screen (not sure what the official name is, some random pictures) but when I interact with the keyboard I'm already logged in.

My IT department is suggesting that I should sleep my computer rather than hibernate it (because sleep is now "modern standby" and "hibernate is obsolete"; and I confirmed that 'modern standby' is available via a `powercfg /a`), but as far as I can tell 'sleep' doesn't actually ... do anything.

What is supposed to happen here when I ask my computer to "sleep"?

Comment: Nothing because connected standby isn't _really_ a low-power state. Certainly it's a little more nuanced, but that's the gist of it. // If your IT department had to pay the power bills, they would not suggest this.

Comment: It *should* turn off your screen and put your computer into a mode where it is nearly turned off but able to come back on quickly. If it simply goes to the lock screen then there is something wrong with how it is configured on your machine or something like the keyboard or mouse is waking it up straight away.

Comment: Should it lock the computer in addition to turning off the screen? I'll try disconnecting all the peripherals and sleeping it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: What does your prompt show when entering `powercfg -lastwake`?

Comment: Oh and lock on sleep should be a configurable behavior, but I can't recall off the top of my head whether it's on by default or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that Sleep is now Modern Standby, although Microsoft still
calls it "Sleep".

You could study the documentation for
[Modern Standby](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby),
but pay attention to the following excerpts:

> The complexity of Modern Standby is a result of keeping the system alive to process background tasks, while ensuring that the system stays quiet enough to achieve long battery life.

And also :

> On-demand transitions to active mode can occur in response to user inputs, interrupts from networking devices and other hardware events

Sleep stores the entire state of your computer in RAM and puts most
components in low-power state, except of course the RAM.
Sleep saves on power, but a power-cut will lose everything that is in RAM.

Sleep needs that all devices and drivers should correctly support this
state. Evidently your computer doesn't, so it wakes up immediately.
Actually, my own computer does exactly the same, immediately waking up.

Hibernate is absolutely not obsolete! It saves more on power than sleep,
by storing the computer state on disk and really shutting down.
It will withstand power-cuts and will not lose anything.

I would suggest that you ignore the "advice" you got from IT and continue
on hibernating your computer. It would be healthier to infrequently
really shutdown the computer, to reinitialize Windows
on boot to a known starting state.

Comment: Sadly hibernate is not available if you use "native boot from vxd".  I've never understood why that limitation (still) exists.  (This has nothing to do with the OP's question, or your fine answer.  It's just that this answer has given me a place to gripe.)